# how to check if app is installed in user device when redirecting from deeplink

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have deep links in my app and I wonder if there is anyway to attach some function to it to check if my app is installed on the user device , and if it does proceed the operation but if it doesnt , then redirect to the app store to download. I couldnt really find any information about it on the web. I saw [this](https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link) library but If I understand it right, its for in-app redirection to another app, my will is to use my link that the user user in his browser to redirect to my app.

example:

```
appId://somePath // if app exist its redirect to the screen in the app

appId://somePath // if app doest exist redirect to app store to the app page
```

the first part is done but the second part is one big question mark for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is no way to find if application is installed or not(from outside like browser).

You can integrate branch.io - https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/

You just have to configure the dashboard for both conditions(installed/not installed) and generate a link which you can share the same link on the browser.

Comment: is it paid or free?

Comment: It's free for some limited features, and if you want more features there are some plans available but that depends on the requirement.